# Video not working for mobile sites

Tags: html, video

I am working with mobile websites. The main concept is video playing. I have used HTML5 video tag and it's comfortable in most devices, but the controls are not visible in the Android and Windows mobile platforms.

HTML:

```
<video poster="imageURL.jpg" controls>
  <source src="videoURL.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Or let me which player is good for mobile web site.

Comment: The supported codec is different from browser to browser. Go to http://html5test.com to see what video formats your mobile browser supports. You can include a link to each video type as separate source elements in the video tag.

Comment: I suggest use this player for html 5 video http://www.videojs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code.i guess its working.

```
 <video id="myvideo" poster="imageURL.jpg" controls>
  <source src="videoURL.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>


if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') >=0) {
 document.getElementById('myvideo').controls = true;
}
```